# How to position an input type button not to move on resizing my browser?

Tags: html, css

I'm an absolute beginner & would be grateful to know how to position an input type button in a form not to move on re sizing my browser.

```
<form action="HereYouGo.php" method="post">
    <center>
        <p>
            <input type="text" name="fullname" size="25" />
            <input type="text" name="email" size="25" />
            <input type="password" name="psw" size="25" />
        </p>
    </center>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Here You Go!" />
    </p>
    <center>
        <h4>By clicking "Here You Go!" you agree with our terms &amp; conditions and private policy.</h4>
    </center>
</form>
```

Comment: could you please include your code

Comment: If you set the `position` to `absolute`, the button will not move. But if the button is inside a `div` or something similar, that too should be made non-resizeable.

Comment: HERE'S MY CODE:<form action="HereYouGo.php" method="post"><center>
<p><input type="text" name="fullname" size="25" /> <input type="text" name="email" size="25" /> <input type="password" name="psw" size="25" /></p>
</center>
<p>                                                                                <input type="submit" value="Here You Go!" /></p>
<center>
<h4>By clicking "Here You Go!" you agree with our terms &amp; conditions and private policy.</h4>
</center></form>

Comment: `not to move on re sizing my browser` so where it will be? Can you draw a picture with couple of different resolutions for illustrative?

Comment: Ok how do i place the button in the center of the webpage provided it should not float around even when i resize my browser window

Comment: @KennyKamei What you are asking is not clear. I second Mosh Feu request for illusatration images